# Why do I get can only join an iterable for a list and how can I solve this?

Tags: python, list, generator

I'm new to python and I'm trying to do the "Band name generator" kata on codewars but I'm having trouble with the join function and I do not know why. It says "can only join an iterable" but I am trying to join a list which is an iterable so I do not understand what is the issue here and how to solve this.
Thank you so much in advance!

```
import re
regex = r'^[a-z]$|^([a-z]).*\1$'

def split(name):
    return [char for char in name]


def band_name_generator(name):
    if (re.search(regex, name)):
        x = split(name).append(split(name)[1:])
        return "".join(x)
    else:
        return "The " + name.capitalize()

print(band_name_generator("alaska"))
```

Comment: You can really simplify the logic - see the post below.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what do you expect `split(name).append(split(name)[1:])` to mean? What result do you expect `x` to have? Did you *check* this? Did you try to read the documentation for the `.append` method? Also, when asking a question, please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message. Generally, they explain exactly what is wrong and where in the code the problem occurred - when properly read and understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the built-in function `list()` does the same as your split function, so I would suggest using that if you can.

You can also splice strings as if they were lists and then join them together so the function `band_name_generator()` could be rewritten as follows

```
def band_name_generator(name):
    if (re.search(regex, name)):
        x = name + name[1:]
        return x
   
    return "The " + name.capitalize()
```

The final else statement is not necessary as when a function returns it stops.

I would also suggest to use `regex.compile` as recommended by the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^[a-z]$|^([a-z]).*\1$')
p.search(name)
```

In any case, the problem in your code is that `append()` does not return a new list but modifies the original one, so your value x is empty (`NoneType`)